# Настройка и оформление меню

Tags: android, android-menu

Создать меню не составит никому  трудности, но возник вопрос как его можно настроить ??? Вплоть до создания своего лейаута для него!

Приблизительно чтобы придать меню такой вид: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Какими средствами можно добиться такого ???**

Comment: Компонент называется popupWindow. Вот тут документация http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Comment: Сделать такое меню нет сложности, но как говорил ранее - сам использовал popupWindow, мне кажется очень хорошая замена для вашей задачи.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, спасибо...буду пробовать!!! 

Не подскажете еще, как установить для popupWindow анимацию и тень ???

Comment: popupWindow.setElevation(45); с анимациями всё хорошо там, выбирайте и ставьте. Будет время завтра я скину пример popup сюда, чтоб вопрос был закрыт, я когда искал мне ничего не понравилось, делала в итоге сам с оф источника. Всё оказалось красивей и проще на мой взгляд.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, этот метод работает только для API > 21. Для меньшего API нельзя нечего сделать ?